# WPF - How Can I make a custom Border

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

How Can I make a custom Border like this:

[image]

i want use a Polygon at the top of border but i don't know how do it :(

Comment: You asked the same question 3 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156489/wpf-how-can-i-make-a-custom-border

Comment: i removed it because no one answer my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a custom `Decorator`. See the following link for an example of how to do it: http://blog.pixelingene.com/2007/06/balloondecorator-source-code/