# Creating a custom shaped border

Tags: wpf, border, customization

I need to create a border with some kind of arrow in its edge. This is the picture -

[image: custom shaped border]

And I need to be able to move this arrow (it points the selected item in a listbox outside the border).

Thanks.

Comment: I think this will point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158127/wpf-how-can-i-make-a-custom-border

Comment: I've seen that before. I'm not sure I can move this triangle that way (at least it's not simple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done is to put this triangle as an image in the ListBox (left to the border), and I'm showing it only on the selected item (with DataBinding).

Not to "stright", but works great (after I was sure I wouldn't be able to do that).