# Wpf: How to make a custom border

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'd like to learn how to make a custom border that has a unique shape. I'm using .Net 4.0 and I already have a geometry defined based on a path. I don't know how to do all the programming required to clip the child control of the border, resize everything, etc...

I found this answer which has a link to a blog post explaining how this is done, but the explanation is sparse and the source code download link is broken. So in effect, this is not an answered question: [WPF - How Can I make a custom Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158127/wpf-how-can-i-make-a-custom-border)

Here's the solution I have so far but the border doesn't resize to fit the child control as you would expect:

```
public class TrapezoidBorder : Border
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GlowBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("GlowBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(TrapezoidBorder), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CornerRadius", typeof(double), typeof(TrapezoidBorder), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(8.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OuterGlowBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("OuterGlowBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(TrapezoidBorder), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RenderIsMouseOverProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RenderIsMouseOver", typeof(bool), typeof(TrapezoidBorder), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnRenderIsMouseOverChanged)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RenderIsPressedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RenderIsPressed", typeof(bool), typeof(TrapezoidBorder), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnRenderIsPressedChanged)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BorderWidth", typeof(double), typeof(TrapezoidBorder), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(2.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BorderBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(TrapezoidBorder), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Background", typeof(Brush), typeof(TrapezoidBorder), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public Brush Background
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(BackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BackgroundProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush BorderBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(BorderBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BorderBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    public double BorderWidth
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(BorderWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BorderWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool RenderIsPressed
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(RenderIsPressedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RenderIsPressedProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool RenderIsMouseOver
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(RenderIsMouseOverProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RenderIsMouseOverProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush OuterGlowBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(OuterGlowBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OuterGlowBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    public double CornerRadius
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush GlowBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(GlowBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GlowBrushProperty, value); }
    }
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        var rc = new Rect(0, 0, this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight);
        var path = new Path();
        //path.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        //path.Data =
        //    Geometry.Parse(
        //        "M130.91336,-2.6003754 L144.9668,13.820157 144.63235,155.90351 -45.593261,156.07107 -45.425622,-2.264937 z");
        Brush backBrush = GetBackgroundBrush();
        Brush borderBrush = GetBorderBrush();
        Pen borderPen = new Pen(borderBrush, BorderWidth);
        double cornerRadiusCache = CornerRadius;

        var geometry = Geometry.Parse(
            "M130.91336,-2.6003754 L144.9668,13.820157 144.63235,155.90351 -45.593261,156.07107 -45.425622,-2.264937 z");

        drawingContext.PushClip(geometry);
        drawingContext.DrawGeometry(borderBrush, borderPen, geometry);
        drawingContext.Pop();
        //base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        UIElement child = this.Child as UIElement;

        double borderThickness = BorderWidth*2.0;

        if (child != null)
        {
            Size size = new Size();

            bool widthAvail = constraint.Width < borderThickness;
            bool heightAvail = constraint.Height < borderThickness;

            if (!widthAvail)
            {
                size.Width = constraint.Width - borderThickness;
            }

            if (!heightAvail)
            {
                size.Height = constraint.Height - borderThickness;
            }

            child.Measure(size);
            Size desired = child.DesiredSize;

            if (!widthAvail)
            {
                desired.Width += borderThickness;
            }
            if (!heightAvail)
            {
                desired.Height += borderThickness;
            }

            return desired;
            //return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
        }
        return new Size(Math.Min(borderThickness, constraint.Width), Math.Min(borderThickness, constraint.Height));
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize);
    }

    private static void OnRenderIsPressedChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var border = o as TrapezoidBorder;
        if (border != null)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
            {
            }
            border.InvalidateVisual();
        }
    }

    // if the mouse is over the control, this fires
    private static void OnRenderIsMouseOverChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var border = o as TrapezoidBorder;
        if (border != null)
        {
            border.InvalidateVisual();
        }
    }
    protected virtual Brush GetBackgroundBrush()
    {
        Brush b = Background;
        if (b != null)
        {
            return b;
        }

        return Brushes.Orange;
    }
    protected virtual Brush GetBorderBrush()
    {
        Brush b = BorderBrush;
        if (b != null)
        {
            return b;
        }

        return Brushes.DarkGray;
    }
}
```

Here's some XAML where I've tried to use it:

```
<customControls:TrapezoidBorder 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
        Background="Blue" 
        Margin="45" 
        BorderWidth="0" BorderBrush="Crimson">
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource SubGridContainer}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="7*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
                <RowDefinition Height=".5*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="88.5*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="25,0,0,10" Style="{StaticResource LargeHeader}">Customers</TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource SearchBar}">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Search</TextBlock>
                <TextBox x:Name="SearchTerm"
                    Template="{StaticResource TextBoxBaseControlTemplate}" 
                         MinWidth="450" 
                         Margin="3"
                         cal:Message.Attach="[Event KeyDown] = [Action Search($executionContext)]"/>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <RadioButton Name="SortByLastName">Sort by Last Name</RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton Name="SortByFirstName">Soft by First Name</RadioButton>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <ListBox x:Name="AccountRegistrationLogs" 
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AccountRegistrationLogDataTemplate}"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             Background="Beige" Grid.Row="3" FontFamily="Arial" >
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="CadetBlue">
                    </SolidColorBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="LightGray">
                    </SolidColorBrush>
                </ListBox.Resources>
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="AccountRegistrationLogPanelStyle"></StaticResource>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
            <!--<TabControl Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" TabStripPlacement="Top" 
            Style="{StaticResource TabControlStyle}" FontSize="16">
                <TabItem Header="MainTab">
                    <Border Margin="10">
                        <TextBlock Text="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."/>
                    </Border>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="VeryVeryLongTab" />
                <TabItem Header="Tab" />
            </TabControl>-->
        </Grid>
    </customControls:TrapezoidBorder>
```

Thanks

Comment: BorderWidth="0" might make your border invisible

Comment: True... but this doesn't solve much. If I set a background color I can definitely see the border...it has the correct shape. The problem is that the border contents which are specified in the XAML above don't appear inside of it and the border is way smaller than the contents.